# Can I make Gedit not ask to save a blank file?

Tags: gedit

If you type something in Gedit then erase it and try to close Gedit, it will ask if you want to save the file, even though it's blank. Is there a way to avoid this? Notepad++ and Atom for example do this by default.

I've checked through Gedit's preferences, `man gedit`, and did a quick Google but couldn't find anything related.

I'm using the default Gedit 3.28.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I've been using *gedit* for a long time but I haven't seen such option maybe it's just a basic behaviour and the editor gives a warning of what may happen to the information if you close it. But yes if the file is empty they could implement some workaround to drop this step.

Comment: @JoKeR Yeah true, the warning is useful if you need the text in the edit history, but I almost never do. Although if you undo right back to the start, the file is blank and there's still info in the edit history, but then it doesn't prompt to save. Hmm...

Comment: My gedit closes immediately, you made change and looks empty and be able to restore something on it. It doesn't close without notification.

Comment: It does not matter that the editor is empty! you've got some edits in your history! a changed and unsaved file (press `CTRL+Z`), that's why it gives you a notification. It just thinks you've edited the file. I have not seen such an option too yet.